# printing shapes in one line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print 2 circles pattern in one row and two in the next row like this

[image]

Here is my Code:

```
cell = {}
row = 5
col = 5

for i in range(0,row):
    for j in range(0,col):
        if((j == 0 or j == col-1) and (i!=0 and i!=row-1)) :
            cell[(i,j)] = '*'
                   #end='' so that print statement should not change the line.
        elif( ((i==0 or i==row-1) and (j>0 and j<col-1))):
            cell[(i,j)] = '*'
        else:
            cell[(i,j)] = " "
        print(cell[(i, j)], end=" ")
    print(end='\n')
```

And with this code I'm getting the output as follows:

[image]

what should I change in this code to make it correct?

Comment: If you clearly see the figure looks like a square. You just need to leave some space(s) in the corner to make it look like a circle.

Comment: Actually i am happy with this shape I just want to add same shape in front of it like in the first image

Comment: Well, you wrote your code to print one shape, so it prints one shape. What have you tried in terms of making it print multiple?

Comment: yes, I am asking that how to change this code to print 2 circles in one row and 2 in another row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially need a template for top/bottom of a circle and the middle part of a circle.

Then you need to print enough of them per line:

```
nums = 7   # only squares supported
amount = 3 # shapes per line & shape rows in total
spacer = 2 # space horizontally, vertically it is 1 line

# prepare shapes
top_botton = f" {'*'*(nums-2)} "
middle = f"*{' '*(nums-2)}*"
space_h = " " * spacer

for row in range(amount * nums):
    # detect which row we are in
    mod_row = row % nums     

    # bottom or top of row
    if mod_row in (0, nums-1):
        print(*([top_botton]*amount), sep=space_h )
        if mod_row == nums-1:
            print()

    # middle of row
    else:
        print(*([middle]*amount), sep=space_h)
```

Output:

```
# nums = 5, count = 2
 ***    *** 
*   *  *   *
*   *  *   *
*   *  *   *
 ***    ***

 ***    ***
*   *  *   *
*   *  *   *
*   *  *   *
 ***    ***

# nums = 7, count = 3
 *****    *****    ***** 
*     *  *     *  *     *
*     *  *     *  *     *
*     *  *     *  *     *
*     *  *     *  *     *
*     *  *     *  *     *
 *****    *****    *****

 *****    *****    *****
*     *  *     *  *     *
*     *  *     *  *     *
*     *  *     *  *     *
*     *  *     *  *     *
*     *  *     *  *     *
 *****    *****    *****

 *****    *****    *****
*     *  *     *  *     *
*     *  *     *  *     *
*     *  *     *  *     *
*     *  *     *  *     *
*     *  *     *  *     *
 *****    *****    *****
```

The distance between the circles is handled by the `sep=...` of the print statement. It prints the decomposed list of (amount) shapes.

You could as well handle a "single char" printer like you did for your single cirle, but all those loops in loops and values modular checking are getting confusing fast.

Comment: What if I want to place these 4 shapes on a 20x20 grid then how can I do this?

Comment: @zik You pull over your coding gloves and modify this example code to fit your needs - what you do not do is adding more things to your question and moving the goal post to be reached to answer a question.

Answer (score 0):

for i in range(0,row):
for j in range(0,col):
if((j == 1 or j == col-1) and (i!=0 and i!=row+1)) :
cell[(i,j)] = '*'
elif( ((i==0 or i==row-1) and (j>0 and j<col+1))):
cell[(i,j)] = '*'
else:
cell[(i,j)] = " "
print(cell[(i,j)], end=" ")
print(end='\n')

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).